# Write Checkbox to CakePHP Session

Tags: cakephp, if-statement, checkbox, controller

i would like to have a form where i have an additional checkbox (will not store input to db) which will be readout in the controller.

For Example.
In a Job Edit view i can select a user. Under this user is a checkbox. This checkbox will send after i have assigned the Job to the User an email.

In my Controller i write

```
$post_array = $this->request->data;
if ($post_array['Job']['mailcheck'] == NULL) {
    // DO SOMETHING
} else {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

But it doesn´t read out the checkbox value...

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While mark's answer is correct, allow me to elaborate.

Keep in mind that checkboxes sometimes behave curiously. An unchecked checkbox may not get posted at all, and that may be why your condition fails.

Regarding why you couldn't make it work:

It seems you are performing a redirect in either case, which is why you never see the edit form. Check to see if you missed something or just try this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if (!empty($this->request->data['Job']['mailcheck'])) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'sendMails',$id));
    } else {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'sorted'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This suffices:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['Job']['mailcheck'])) {
    // yes, checkbox was selected
} else {
    // no, it was not selected
}
```

Comment: hi Mark,
when i use your example no error will display.
But when i click in my detail view on "assign User" it doesn´t display the edit form where i can assign the user.

My Code

    if (!empty($this->request->data['Job']['mailcheck'])) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'sendMails',$id));
    } else {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'sorted'));
    }


I will redirected directly to the "sorted" view.

What i do wrong ?

Comment: maybe you got it wrong? switch the two statements if your desired result is supposed to be the opposite

Comment: i try it out. i don´t get my "assignUser" editview. when i delete the complete if statement i get my edit view

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your `// do something` part? Try debugging the posted data, if you're using multiple checkboxes, 'mailcheck' may be an array, not a single value. To debug, simply do `debug($this->request->data);` with debug enabled in your `app/Config/core.php`